# SQLite update hook in a multi process application

Tags: sqlite, hook, multiprocess

I am using sqlite in a multi process scenario. The sqlite library was compiled with the threadsafe serialized mode ([`-DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1`](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html)).

I want to be notified on datachanges and found [`sqlite3_update_hook`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html). Every process would register it's own update hook to be notified of changes to the database.

The question now is: If a process A modifies the database, will the update hook of process B be called? Or do hooks only work within the same process or the same connection?

Sadly, the documentation is not very clear about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html) says:

> The sqlite3_update_hook() interface registers a callback function with the database connection identified by the first argument

The database connection is a local object; the hook will not fire for any other connection, in this or another process.

Comment: I read this, but I don't think thats obvious from that part. They should make it a little more explicit.

Comment: Agree, it should say "invoked whenever a row is updated, inserted or deleted in a rowid table" ON THE SAME CONNECTION